# Apache Load Balancer Without Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, load-balancing

I am trying to use Apache as a Load Balancer without reverse proxy so the servers will actually connect with the clients.

Tried this with redirect:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.229.4:6789
    BalancerMember http://192.168.229.6:6789
</Proxy>
    ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* balancer://mycluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
```

Or with rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap  lb       "rnd:/etc/httpd/conf/list.txt"
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://${lb:servers}/$1"     [P,L]
```

But in both cases traffic on the servers is from and to the load balancer (checked with tcpdump).

Comment: Apache can only load balance with proxy.  What you are looking for is a *network* load balancer that will modify the target address of the server (and the source on the return).  This LB inspects the packet and modifies it.  Apache looks at the query, but cannot modify the IP packets.

Comment: @Nic3500 one can change the target address using the rewrite module: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirect-ip-address-to-domain-name-apache. I just don't know how to do it LB.

Comment: Ah ok, yes not quite the same thing as I mentioned.  You can send a redirect to the client to tell him to go to another IP.  What I am talking about is a device that will change the address at the IP layer, so the client will never get a redirect.  If you want the users to be distributed over 2 IP addresses, then you can use a round robin DNS.  That DNS will respond with IP1, then IP2, then IP2, ...  If you really want to redirect in Apache, indeed I do not know how to do that.  But in an enterprise level, we would not do it since we have access to the other mechanisms I talked about.

Comment: OK, so how I can redirect based on a list of other servers? Let's say using round robin?